# Unexpected token error when integrating godaddy domain API

Tags: php, curl, godaddy-api

**Error**

> {"message":"Unexpected token '","body":"{'type':'A','name':'tarunDhiman','data':'166.62.81.221','ttl':3600}"}

**Code**

```php
$data = "{'type':'A','name':'tarunDhiman','data':'166.62.81.221','ttl':3600}";

$url = "https://api.godaddy.com/v1/domains/{domain}/records";

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept : application/json',
    'Authorization : sso-key {key}:{token}' );

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
print $response ;
exit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is solved by the help of **@Slaiv206** And below the working code.

```html
$data = '[{ "type":"A", "name":"tarunDhiman", "data":"255.255.255.0", "ttl":3600 }]';

$url = "https://api.godaddy.com/v1/domains/{domain}/records";

$headers = array(
 'Content-Type: application/json',
 'Accept : application/json',
 'Authorization : sso-key {key}:{secret}' );

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
print $response ;
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the header Authorization string is:

```
Authorization: sso-key {KEY}:{SECRET}
```

and not:

```
Authorization : sso-key {key}:{token}
```

and in the json string use double quotes instead single quotes:

```
'{ "type":"A", "name":"tarunDhiman", "data":"166.62.81.221", "ttl":3600 }'
```

Comment: and in the json string use double quotes instead single quotes: {  
   "type":"A",
   "name":"tarunDhiman",
   "data":"166.62.81.221",
   "ttl":3600
}

Comment: When use '{ "type":"A", "name":"tarunDhiman", "data":"166.62.81.221", "ttl":3600 }' , double quotes this giving below error.

{"code":"INVALID_BODY","message":"Request body doesn't fulfill schema, see details in `fields`","responseModel":"Error","fields":[{"message":"is not a array","path":"records","code":"UNEXPECTED_TYPE"}]}

Comment: check the documentation,  it requires an array in the parameters you send

Comment: yes it requires an array and the issue solved. My mistake is i am using single quites in josn data. Thank you buddy